# Set Cron Job on Personal Computer/Server

Tags: server

Set up WAMP and running Magento off of it on my personal computer.

Don't have a website or anything like that, but need to set up cron job to run every 15 minutes for my Amazon Seller store.

How can I configure this to work?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you'll need to use the [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IE/windows7/schedule-a-task). Windows does not have cron.

with the above you use your script directly from URL, means if you want to run `cron_amazon.php` script from cron setting and you want to test the result for the same then you can directly run this file from localhost like http://www.localhost/XXXX/cron_amazon.php

hope this will help you.

Comment: trying to run the cron job thru m2epro (magento extension)